# How can I sort through logs using regex

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I have a directory full of log files, each one named for each day, ie, "log.2016-09-26" but they go back a long ways. I'm using filebeat to grab these logs from this directory, but my issue is that I only want the past 2 weeks/14 days. Filebeat wants a regex to filter out what files to exclude. What is the best way to filter these logs?

Comment: Sorry, regex only "understand" plain text. You can use `log\.2016-09-(2[0-6]|1[2-9])` here, but it will become a bit more difficult in case of `2017-01-02`

Comment: Thank you for the help! But this won't work for tomorrow, or the next day. I'm looking for something that I don't have to change daily.

Comment: Ok, so, not a regex for sure.

Comment: There is no way for this to be a regex?

Comment: Delete the older files, then read all files.

Comment: Or you can use [environnement variables](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/using-environ-vars.html). If you export the names of the files to exclude before starting, you'll be able to use the environnement variable in your configuration in the exclude_files configuration option. You'll have to stop, generate the list of files not to read, export and restart filebeat every day, with a cron job/script

Comment: What if I were to create a job that moves all logs older than X days into a separate directory? Is this something that would work?